Can I get the related data directly when using a join query in django?
Well considering two models:
class School(models.Model):
    name = TextField()

class Student(models.Model):
    school = ForeignKey(School
        related_name=students
    )
    firstname = TextField()

And the query:
School.objects.filter(Q(name="oldschool") & Q(
    Q(students__firstname="hello") | Q(students__firstname="testname")
))

I retrieve the schools. However there is a join/subquery obviously executed, yet I do not get the student information. I also wish to get the student information for which the "first name is set".
Can I make django orm actually fill in a students_set, so I do not have to do multiple lookups later? (having to iterate over the schools and check per school).

The way you normally do is with a .prefetch_related(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

schools = School.objects.filter(
    Q(students__firstname='hello') | Q(students__firstname='testname'),
    name='oldschool',
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'students',
        Student.objects.filter(Q(firstname='hello') | Q(firstname='testname')),
    )
)

for school in schools:
    for student in school.students.all():
        print(student)
this will make one additional query for all Students for all Schools, so two queries. This is done to reduce the bandwidth from the database to the Django/Python layer.
If there is only one school however, it makes more sense to query from the Student view:
Student.objects.filter(
    Q(firstname='hello') | Q(firstname='testname'), school__name='oldschool'
)
We can also include the School data then, but that is probably not a good idea:
Student.objects.filter(
    Q(firstname='hello') | Q(firstname='testname'), school__name='oldschool'
).select_related('school')
